# $_REQUEST var is empty from post send

Tags: php, javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm doing a ajax function for wp. But i get always the response 0. I see the code of the file admin-ajax.php and see this:

```
if ( empty( $_REQUEST['action'] ) )
    die( '0' );
```

This is my js function ajax.

```
function fnc(){

            var ajax=new  XMLHttpRequest();
            ajax.open("POST", "<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php");



                ajax.onreadystatechange= function(){
                    if (ajax.readyState === 4) {
                        if (ajax.status === 200) {
                            alert(ajax.responseType);
                            alert(ajax.responseText);
                        } else {
                            alert('There was a problem with the request.');
                        }
                    }
                }
                ajax.send("action=some_function");


        }
```

Comment: Did you pass the var action to the PHP file via GET or POST? http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php

Comment: Show your request headers

Comment: What does firebug or chrome  tool says when the request is submitted? What are the parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to have the `send` string be used as form data, you will probably need to add the following header:

```
ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Without this, PHP will not turn the raw POST data into `$_POST`/`$_REQUEST` variables.

Answer (score -1):

```
$.ajax({
          type:'POST',
          url:"<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
          data:'', //  what you want to post
          success:function(data){
                    alert(data);
              });
             }
          });
        }
```

try this

Comment: Why would you assume jQuery?

Comment: that the fast and nice way to handle the ajax

Comment: @cbuckley: Why would you *not* assume jQuery?

Comment: @Sorpigal because the OP is using a native XMLHttpRequest object; probably for a reason.

Comment: A reason like ignorance, given the question. If you're not using jQuery *you probably should be*; it's reasonable to recommend it.

Comment: If the purpose was to recommend jQuery, you could (a) have left that as a comment, or (b) mention that in your answer.

Comment: acknowledged i'll do that in future thanks @cbuckley. But i thought that the User might have used the jQuery in the code so it can speed up the task, thats is :)

Comment: I know jquery, i don't use here because the default theme of wp don't included it by default, could be enable with wp enqueque script but i don't try. Maybe another day. And wp use jQuery not $

Comment: ok good if you are using the defaults :) i also like doing that i only said to try that. but i guess without jquery your site might be slow in some respect and sooner or latter you might shift to jQuery. No offence :)

Answer (score -1):

```
If you want to use javascript and XMLHttpRequest this is the full way to do that :)


function ajax_post(){
// Create our XMLHttpRequest object
var ajax=new  XMLHttpRequest();

// Create data to send to our PHP file

var url = "xyz.php";
var fn = document.getElementById("a").value;
var ln = document.getElementById("b").value;
var variable = fn+" hello "+ln;
hr.open("POST", url, true);


// Set content type header  for sending url encoded variables

ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

// Get the onreadystatechange event for the XMLHttpRequest
ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
        var return_data = ajax.responseText;
            alert(ajax.return_data);
            // Send the data to PHP now... and wait for response to update the status div
           ajax.send(variable); // Actually execute the request    
    }
}



}
```